# Sometimes I am round. Now it is your turn

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Sometimes I am a cousin of a night in strong wind.
>   Sometimes I like a baseball stick man.
>   Sometimes I one of the most controversial philanthropist.
>   Sometimes I am round. Now it is your turn.
>   Who/What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> a robin.

Sometimes I am a cousin of a night in strong wind.

> The American robin looks a lot like the common nightingale.

Sometimes I like a baseball stick man.

> Robin is Batman's sidekick.

Sometimes I am one of the most controversial philanthropists.

> Robin Hood stole from the rich and gave to the poor.

Sometimes I am round. Now it is your turn.

> A round robin is a style of tournament.

Answer (score 3):

If I may be allowed to stretch it... a lot

> are you a nightingale?
>  night in strong wind -> nightingale
>  philanthropist -> Florence nightingale
>  baseball player -> Dave nightingale
>  sometimes I am round -> the nightingale bird when still in his egg.

Comment: This is not the intended answer, however the first line is mostly correct. The intended understanding of the 'cousin' is more 'far cousin' than yours.